# Get means of every n rows without groups

Tags: r, date

My data (df) looks similar to this

| date | address1 | address2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2015-01-01 | 2 | 8 |
| 2015-01-02 | 3 | 7 |
| 2015-01-03 | 7 | 3 |
| 2015-01-04 | 3 | 1 |
| 2015-01-05 | 9 | 4 |
| 2015-01-06 | 3 | 4 |

I want to get 3 days average of value at each address like this

| date | address1 | address2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2015-01-03 | 4 | 6 |
| 2015-01-06 | 5 | 3 |

I have tried to extract date by every three days like `d<-date[seq(1,length(date),by=3)]`. I calculated the value using `dat<-rowsum(df[,-1],rep(1:6,each=3))`. Then divided the whole dataframe by 3 and combined **d** and **dat**.

I have tried to find **rowmean** works like **rowsum**, but did not manage to. Also, rolling means does not suit my case as it averages rows with overlapping (multiple use of rows).

Please help me to improve my method. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solutions below use the input shown reproducibly in the Note at the end. The first two use only base R.  The first requires that the number of rows be a multiple of 3 but the others so not have this restriction.

**1) rowsum** Create a grouping vector, date, and use it in the second argument to rowsum giving the numeric matrix shown.

```
nr <- nrow(df)
date <- df$date[ 3 * col(matrix(0, 3, nr/3)) ]
rowsum(df[-1], date) / 3
##            address1 address2
## 2015-01-03        4        6
## 2015-01-06        5        3
```

**2) aggregate** Alternately use aggregate giving a 3 column data frame.

```
nr <- nrow(df)
date <- ave(df$date, seq(0, length = nr) %/% 3, FUN = max)
aggregate(df[-1], data.frame(date), mean)
##         date address1 address2
## 1 2015-01-03        4        6
## 2 2015-01-06        5        3
```

**3) collap** collap from the collapse package can be used in place of aggregate.  date is from (2).

```
library(collapse)

collap(df[-1], date)
##         date address1 address2
## 1 2015-01-03        4        6
## 2 2015-01-06        5        3
```

**4) data.table** Using data.table and date from (2) this returns a data.table (which is also a data frame).

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(df[, -1])[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = .(date)]
##          date address1 address2
## 1: 2015-01-03        4        6
## 2: 2015-01-06        5        3
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form is:

```
df <- 
structure(list(date = c("2015-01-01", "2015-01-02", "2015-01-03", 
"2015-01-04", "2015-01-05", "2015-01-06"), address1 = c(2L, 3L, 
7L, 3L, 9L, 3L), address2 = c(8L, 7L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create group of every 3 rows and take mean of all the "address" columns -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
  group_by(grp = ceiling(row_number()/3)) %>%
  summarise(date = last(date), 
            across(starts_with('address'), mean, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  select(-grp)

#   date       address1 address2
#  <date>        <dbl>    <dbl>
#1 2015-01-03        4        6
#2 2015-01-06        5        3
```

Another option is to `cut` by 3 days but it will give the date of starting of the group.

```
df %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
  group_by(date = cut(date, '3 days')) %>%
  summarise(across(starts_with('address'), mean, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another base R option with `aggregate` + `ave`

```
aggregate(
    . ~ date,
    transform(
        df,
        date = ave(date, ceiling(seq_along(date) / 3), FUN = max)
    ),
    mean
)
```

gives

```
        date address1 address2
1 2015-01-03        4        6
2 2015-01-06        5        3
```